# Can a PLL work with a sine signal as its XIN?

Tags: rf, signal, pll

I need to generate a 150.012MHz signal. I am going to this with a PLL for RF purposes, so I am thinking to buy a 10Mhz osc with a sine output, will this work with all PLLs? as they are digital I'm not pretty sure. Or should I buy an square oscillator?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What phase detector do you plan to use for your PLL?

Comment: I am planing to use this PLL https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/si4133.pdf it already has a phase detector

Comment: That datasheet isn't very informative. It's clear that one option is CMOS levels, so if you can, I'd go with a reference source with CMOS levels. If you would really rather use a sine-output oscillator, it looks like it'd probably work (as long as you ac-couple and meet the sensitivity requirement on pg 8), but it would be a good idea to test it on a demo board before comitting to the design.

Comment: Yes. I'm doing a demo board befor the final design but the problem is I have to wait several weeks to have the component.  On pg 4 there is a -0.3V limitation for all the inputs, including Xin, so I was confused.

Comment: Since they are recommending users to ac-couple the input, there is probably an internal bias circuit to set the dc level at the XIN pin to around VCC/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAQ @ https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si41xxFAQ.pdf

States that either a sine wave or a square wave is acceptable.

"Q: Should the reference source have a sine wave or a square wave output?
A: The reference source can have either a square wave or sine wave output. The reference amplifier has a large gain that converts the incoming sine wave to a square wave. Therefore, both sine and square wave references are processed identically."

From the data sheet the signal should be at least 0.5V p-p in amplitude and coupled with a 560pF capacitor.

kevin

Comment: I didn't know there was a FAQ document. Thank you!